# How to get as json file in angularjs when clicking button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Actually am the starter in angularjs.

I have created one form and it contains two input boxes.

Below the input boxes,

```
<input ng-model="id.todoList" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Enter tasks here">
<input ng-model="id.todoList1" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Enter tasks here">
```

After proceed the input values,

I want the values to be stored as an array. I did!!!!

I can able to push the form inputs whenever i click the submit button.

But, the main problem is...

Suppose i have added the 3 user details, If i go to add the other details means, the stored 3 user details also changes.

Can anyone help on this?

Attached the fiddler link
:[Fiddler Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/HbxY9aKo4qdW2vcmE30E?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a array of json objects while pushing the `todoList` & `todoList1`

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.todos = []
  $scope.id = {   // Creating id object
    todoList: "",
    todoList1: ""
  }

  $scope.addTodo = function() {
    // Creating a json array of objects with 
    // key todoList & todoList1
    $scope.todos.push({
      todoList: $scope.id.todoList,
      todoList1: $scope.id.todoList1,
    })
  }

  $scope.clearAll = function() {
    $scope.todos = []
  }

});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0vq7c85a/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```html
  <body ng-app="plunker">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div class="main">
        <p>Todo App</p>
        <input ng-model="id.todoList" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Enter tasks here">
        <input ng-model="id.todoList1" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Enter tasks here">
        <button ng-click="addTodo()">Add</button>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $index">
            {{todo}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.todos = []
  $scope.todoList = "";

  $scope.addTodo = function(){
    var temp =  $scope.id;
    $scope.todos.push({"todoList":$scope.id.todoList,"todoList1":$scope.id.todoList1});
    console.log($scope.todos);
    $scope.id.todoList = '';
    $scope.id.todoList1 = '';
  }

  


});
</script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can change to this

```
<button ng-click="addTodo(id)">Add</button>
```

and get value of form in js

```
id.todoList
id.todoLIst1
```